# Groovy: printing the map value

Tags: java, groovy

I have the following code which sorts the chatentries after the day and group them. I am facing a problem to print the map and the key value at the commented position.

I am getting the following error in the platform:

> org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: could not initialize proxy
>   - no Session:

**code**

```
List<?> chatList = chatService.limitedChatResult(eventStatus.getFlexiObject().getId(), 10, 10); 
getLogger().info("chatList: " + chatList.size());

def sortedMap = [:];
List<Chat> dayChatEntries = null;
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy");
int x = 0;
getLogger().info("sortedMap before starting the loop: map --> " + sortedMap);
for(Chat chat: chatList){
    String day = sdf.format(chat.getLastWrite());
    if (sortedMap.containsKey(day)) {
        getLogger().info(x + " day: " + day);
        getLogger().info("sortedMap: " + sortedMap); //I can not print the map at this position 
        getLogger().info("sortedMap key: " + sortedMap[day]);
        sortedMap.get(day).add(chat);
                        getLogger().info("a new chat object was added to map list");                
    } else {
        getLogger().info(x + " day is not in the map: " + day);
        dayChatEntries = new ArrayList<Chat>();
        dayChatEntries.add(chat);
        sortedMap.put(day, dayChatEntries); 
        getLogger().info("The day has been added! ");
    }
    x++;
}
```

**output**

```
22:25:52,928 INFO (http-0.0.0.0-0.0.0.0-8080-11) chatList: 10
22:25:52,930 INFO (http-0.0.0.0-0.0.0.0-8080-11) sortedMap before starting the loop: map --> [:]
22:25:52,932 INFO (http-0.0.0.0-0.0.0.0-8080-11) 0 day is not in the map: 24.11.2017
22:25:52,934 INFO (http-0.0.0.0-0.0.0.0-8080-11) The day has been added!
22:25:52,935 INFO (http-0.0.0.0-0.0.0.0-8080-11) 1 day: 24.11.2017
```

**Another output**

```
        getLogger().info("sortedMap size after the sorting: " + sortedMap.size()); //sortedMap size after the sorting: 2
        //getLogger().info("first message: " + sortedMap.get("24.11.2017")[0].getMsg());    //output: first message: Test --> and then the consequential error.
        getLogger().info("first message: " + sortedMap.get("24.11.2017")[0].getFromName()); //output: first message: DUMMY --> and then the consequential error
        //getLogger().info("first message: " + sortedMap.get("24.11.2017").getClass().getName()) //output: ArrayList --> and then the consequential error. 
        getLogger().info("first message: " + sortedMap.get("24.11.2017")); // no output --> just the consequential error
        getLogger().info("first message: " + sortedMap.get("24.11.2017")[0].getClass().getName());  //output: first message: de.tp.em.core.business.chat.Chat --> and then the consequential error
```

**No consequential error with this code**

```
21:38:09,305 INFO (http-0.0.0.0-0.0.0.0-8080-4) entry key: 24.11.2017
21:38:09,307 INFO (http-0.0.0.0-0.0.0.0-8080-4) entry value: Test
21:38:09,311 INFO (http-0.0.0.0-0.0.0.0-8080-4) entry key: 30.11.2017
21:38:09,312 INFO (http-0.0.0.0-0.0.0.0-8080-4) entry value: Test
```

I want a way to access the ArrayList value of the key from the primefaces with the ui:repeat component to show some data inside the Chat object.

Comment: It is likely that some underlying code is attempting to query a database but the code is not wrapped in the usual Spring/Hibernate framework, so there is no session with the database (hence the error). I'm guessing the code is used elsewhere (where it is appropriately wrapped).

Comment: @MichaelEaster: I think this error is a consequential error. I added some another Output. I do not understand why I can not output the value which is an arrayList filled with Chat objects. The Chat objects are a complex data type. For example if I access it at this way `sortedMap.get("24.11.2017")[0].getFromName()); `I am getting `dummy` as output but when I try to print the Chat object or the ArrayList filled with the Chat objects or the soredMap I am not getting anything printed.